# Blender 2.79b daily builds mark seam missing

Tags: experimental-features

I really like the 2.79b daily builds. 2.79 has been out for a while now and it is darn stable by now. I love it that they still provide daily updates for such an "old" piece of software. But recently I discovered that the mark seam option is missing in the ctrl+e menu. It is still accessible from the search bar. Has it been moved somewhere else (more 2.8 like position?) or is the hotkey just straight up gone? Are other features also missing in the 2.79 daily builds?
That would be kind of a deal breaker and I'd switch back to the release binary. 
But I don't want to, the daily builds have some nifty tweaks and mostly consist of bugfixes so I don't see why they would be much more unstable.

Comment: Sounds strange that they would get rid of the hotkey but keep the option in the software. Might be a minor bug in the daily build or maybe a glitch in the update from one build to another. Have you tried deleting Blender and reinstalling it?